# Change Session ID And Keep Data in PHP Zend

Tags: php, session, zend-framework, session-variables

I want to change the session id once the user has logged in to a custom random session id with my own prefix.

However, when I do the below the session data is lost;

```
Zend_Session:setId('my-new-id');
Zend_Session:start();
```

But if I do the following the session data will still be available;

```
Zend_Session:regenerateId();
Zend_Session:start();
```

Anyidea how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

see in [library/Zend/Session.php:316](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/Session.php#L316):

```
if ( !self::$_sessionStarted ) {
    self::$_regenerateIdState = -1;
} else {
    if (!self::$_unitTestEnabled) {
        session_regenerate_id(true);
    }
    self::$_regenerateIdState = 1;
}
```

> Best practice is to call this after session is started. If called prior to session starting, session id will be regenerated at start time.

also see: [Global Session Management](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.global_session_management.html#zend.session.global_session_management.session_identifiers) with ZF1:

```
$defaultNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
if (!isset($defaultNamespace->initialized)) {
    Zend_Session::regenerateId();
    $defaultNamespace->initialized = true;
}
```

**added:**

Then try this:

```
$commit = Zend_Session::namespaceGet('Default');
Zend_Session::writeClose(false);
// ^ session_commit(); // see Advanced Usage: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.advanced_usage.html#zend.session.advanced_usage.starting_a_session

.. change id with session_id("my-new-id");

// start new session ... 
$namespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Default');
foreach($commit as $idx => $data){
    $namespace->$idx = $data;
}
```

**However!** after calling Zend_Session::writeClose() we cannot restart session with Zend_Session::start() version of [22744dd](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/22744dde7ccbeab9f37abc6028f1e1e2ca838fee/library/Zend/Session.php#L436)

see this issue:

- https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/issues/159
- **fixed version**: https://github.com/itscaro/zf1/blob/bbebe445d8551582cba6f5e9c9c1a8396fb2b322/library/Zend/Session.php#L436

anyway, I recommend watching the documentation of the start session - [Starting a Session](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.session.advanced_usage.html#zend.session.advanced_usage.starting_a_session)

and/or use Zend_Session::regenerateId(); instead of Zend_Session::setId()

Comment: Still doesn't help much as I want to generate a session id with a predefined prefix such as myprefix-*******************

Comment: The details are still being lost :(

Comment: strange -_- with the latest variant should be all right because the Zend_Session:setId() wrapped session_id($id); and all problems with lost data should be fixed /
with $commit you should have copy all data from Zend_Session_Namespace('Default')... needed more detail of your code

Comment: so, when i go Zend_Session::namespaceGet('Default'); i don't get any data but  new Zend_Session_Namespace('Default'); this works. However when using the 2 thing option for some reason the new session data is not applied.

Comment: namespaceGet only retrieved all data of your session-namespace. 'Default' is a name by default(see documentation). 
Where and how assigned the session-data before change id ? check that - [Tutorial Examples](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.basic_usage.html#zend.session.basic_usage.basic_examples)

Comment: I am using the default namespace; 

$a = Zend_Session::namespaceGet('Default');
var_dump($a->identity); <--- returns null

$b = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Default');
var_dump($b->identity);   <-- returns data

Comment: o_o need a code.. anyway, solution with [Zend_Session::namespaceGet](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/Session.php#L849):
1. save all data from session-namespace. 
2. change id with your custom ident - Zend_Session::setId(); 
3. start new Zend_Session_Namespace and restore saved data.

Comment: *!* just in case again: Zend_Session:setId() & Zend_Session:regenerateId() has wrapper for basic php functions - [session_id()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) / [session_regenerate_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php)
see [doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php), for more detail about ident changes

Comment: Finally understood what is happening, I needed to start the session before to get the values of the current session ie: Zend_Session::namespaceGet('Default'), my only problem is that now I am getting "The session has already been started. The session id must be set first.", I tried to use session_unset and session_destroy but still got the same thing

Comment: :) [Advanced Usage](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.advanced_usage.html#zend.session.advanced_usage.starting_a_session)

I wrote above in answer  - "..call session_commit if session is already started" (is a alias of session_write_close)

variants of starting see in Zend_Session documentation 

see edited answer

Comment: writeClose is not doing anything different! I think it still has the state as session started and thus session id cannot be changed.

Comment: should be shutdown! may be a bug о_О what is your ZF1 version ? try this with the simple php functions!
Zend_Session::writeClose() - Shutdown the sesssion, close writing and detach $_SESSION from the back-end storage mechanism.

notice: I used ZF1 ~2-3 years ago, for new projects i recommend use the ZF2 if you can

Comment: With the PHP session_write_close() i still get the The session has already been started error :( I am using ZF 1.12.6